# Dynamic List<T> type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

Is it possible to create a new `List<T>` where the T is dynamically set at runtime?

Cheers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's possible, but not necessarily useful, since you couldn't actually use it from compiled code as strongly typed.  The creation  code would be

```
    Type myType;
    Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
    IList myList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Comment: Please note there is a difference between 'strongly-typed' and 'statically-typed'. You lose static type checking here but myList will prevent you from adding objects which are not valid myType instances.

Comment: It is very useful to me since I am writing a completely dynamic array/list type converter. Thanks!

Comment: You CAN use it strongly typed if you make a "UseAs<T>(T obj)" method and call THAT via reflection and passing in the type as the argument. Then inside that you can do whatever. Maybe make it a local method and capture your outside scope? Or.. pass in a callback.

Just saying, it's possible. I made a library for this personally.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  You can do this via Reflection, using [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) and [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx).

```
IList MakeListOfType(Type listType)
{
    Type listType = typeof(List<>);
    Type specificListType = listType.MakeGenericType(listType);

    return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType);
}
```

Comment: you have a parameter listType and a local field listType, I imagine some people would be confused by that (I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, you won't be able to assign it to a variable that has a generic type since the T in this case will not be decided until runtime. (If you are thinking that the .NET 4.0 covariance feature will help you and let you declare the variable as `IList<SomeSuperType>`, it won't as the `T` is used by `List<T>` for both `in` and `out` purposes.)

Note the unusual List<> syntax in order to access the "unconstructed" generic type.

```
    public static System.Collections.IList ConstructGenericList(Type t)
    {
        return (System.Collections.IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t));
    }
```

Comment: (re variance; that also only works for interfaces / delegates; not classes)

Comment: @Marc, right... I should have wrote `IList<SomeSuperType>`. Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

For DataContractSerializer Known Types you may want to supply not only types from your assembly but also list of that types:

```
public static List<Type> GetKnownTypesForDataContractSerializer()
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type[] array = a.GetExportedTypes();

    List<Type> lista = array.ToList();

    lista = lista.FindAll(item => ((item.IsClass || item.IsEnum) & !item.IsGenericType & !item.IsAbstract == true));



    List<Type> withEnumerable = new List<Type>();
    foreach (Type t in lista)
    {
        withEnumerable.Add(t);   //add basic type

        //now create List<> type
        Type listType = typeof(List<>);
        var listOfType = listType.MakeGenericType(t);

        withEnumerable.Add(listOfType);  //add Type of List<basic type>  
    }

    return withEnumerable;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes using generic you can do something like this

```
    var asd = METHOD<Button>();

    List<t> METHOD<t>()
    {
        return new List<t>();
    }
```

Comment: the type "Button" is hardcoded, that's not runtime

Comment: the OP asked for the t to be determined at runtime. In your example, its set at compile time.