# Convert List<object> to List<Type>, Type is known at runtime

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am implementing some kind of deserialization and struggled with a next problem:

I have `List<object>` and `System.Reflection.Field`, it's `FieldType` can be `List<string>`, `List<int>` or `List<bool>`, so I need to convert from `List<object>` to that types.

```
public static object ConvertList(List<object> value, Type type)
{
   //type may be List<int>, List<bool>, List<string>
}
```

I can write each case separately, but there should be a better way using reflection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
public static object ConvertList(List<object> value, Type type)
{
    var containedType = type.GenericTypeArguments.First();
    return value.Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, containedType)).ToList();
}
```

Example usage:

```
var objects = new List<Object> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

ConvertList(objects, typeof(List<int>)).Dump();
```

I'm not sure how useful this is though... It highlights the insanely useful Convert.ChangeType method I guess!

---

*Update:* Since others have correctly pointed out that this doesn't actually return a `List<T>` (where T is the type in question) and therefore might not fully answer the question at hand, I have chosen to provide a more up to date answer:

```
public static object ConvertList(List<object> items, Type type, bool performConversion = false)
{
    var containedType = type.GenericTypeArguments.First();
    var enumerableType = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable);
    var castMethod = enumerableType.GetMethod(nameof(System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast)).MakeGenericMethod(containedType);
    var toListMethod = enumerableType.GetMethod(nameof(System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList)).MakeGenericMethod(containedType);

    IEnumerable<object> itemsToCast;

    if(performConversion)
    {
        itemsToCast = items.Select(item => Convert.ChangeType(item, containedType));
    }
    else 
    {
        itemsToCast = items;
    }

    var castedItems = castMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { itemsToCast });

    return toListMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { castedItems });
}
```

If you don't need the conversion (so the type of each value is actually correct, and you don't have ints in strings etc), then remove the `performConversion` flag and the associated block.

---

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nSFq22

Comment: This doesn't create a generic list of the specific type. It just converts the inner elements to the specific type, but the list itself is still `List<object>`. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hd4y1c

Comment: Just to get rid of the magic strings `"Cast"` and `"ToList"` you could replace them with `nameof(Enumerable.Cast)` and `nameof(Enumerable.ToList)`.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this helps at all, but can you use Linq Cast?

```
List<object> theList = new List<object>(){ 1, 2, 3};
List<int> listAsInt = theList.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: Why is this not more up-voted?  It seems like the simplest solution that is managed and clean!

Comment: this seems to work straight up. i would recommend this one.

Comment: `theList.Cast<int>()` returns an `IEnumerable<int>` for me, not a `List<int>`

Comment: good point. you would need to `.ToList()` after `.Cast<int>()`

Comment: That's a good solution, but it does not answer to the original question - type is known at runtime, how would you deal with it?

Answer (score 11):

The type is only known at runtime so I guess generic method isn't the way to go

```
public static object ConvertList(List<object> value, Type type)
{
   IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   foreach (var item in value)
   {
      list.Add(item);
   }
   return list;
}
```

Comment: yeah, it's nice solution. Found good thread here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474119/dynamic-listt-type

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to work for the types the OP has mentioned (at least bool and int) because to create a list of objects in the first place the value types have been boxed and thus can't be added to the list. Edit: actually that's not the problem. You need to change `Type[] typeArgs = { type };` in your method to `Type[] typeArgs = { type.GenericTypeArguments.First() };`;

Comment: @Richiban you are right, I wrongly expected `type` to be item's type. Fixed

Answer (score 4):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts list of items into typed list of item of new type
    /// </summary>
    /// <example><code>
    /// Consider source to be List<object>, newItemType is typeof(string), so resulting list wil have type List<string>
    /// </code></example>
    /// <param name="newItemType">New item type</param>
    /// <param name="source">List of objects</param>
    /// <returns>Typed List object</returns>
    public static IList ConvertList(Type newItemType, IList source)
    {
        var listType = typeof(List<>);
        Type[] typeArgs = { newItemType };
        var genericListType = listType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        var typedList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            typedList.Add(item);
        }
        return typedList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static object ConvertList<T>(List<object> value) where T : class
    {
        var newlist = value.Cast<T>().ToList();
        return newlist;
    }
```

or

```
  public static List<T> ConvertList<T>(List<object> value) where T : class
    {
        List<T> newlist = value.Cast<T>().ToList();
        return newlist;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static List<T> ConvertList<T>(List<object> list)
{
    List<T> castedList = list.Select(x => (T)x);
    return castedList;
}
```

Call:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object> {"test", "foo", "bar"};
List<string> stringList = ConvertList<string>(myList);
```

Comment: how can I understand that I should call ConvertList<string>? I only know Type, I can't type ConvertList<type>

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<T> ConvertType<T>(List<object> list) {
    var list2 = new List<T>();
    for(int i=0;i<list.Count;i++) list2.Add((T)list[i]);
    return list2;
}
```

Comment: how can I understand that I should call ConvertList<string>? I only know Type, I can't type ConvertList<type>

Comment: I see, then you'll need to use reflection to make the generic type at runtime, see Guillaume's answer (which I won't repeat).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **extension method** similar to the linq extension method except it takes an argument that is a type instead of a type parameter:

```
public static IList CastToList(this IEnumerable source, Type itemType)
{
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    foreach (var item in source) list.Add(item);
    return list;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
var boxedIntList = list.CastToList(typeof(int)); //type is object{List<int>}
```