Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'
I want to write a function which can transfrom list json to variable. The GenericTypeArgument of List can be int, String, Object..etc.
eg. there has a Class Car, it has a variable "priceList".
public class Car
{
    public List<int> priceList;
}

I want to deserialize string "[1,2]" to priceList, how can I do?
This is my code. But it throws an exception: "Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object] cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]"
using System.Reflection;
using ConsoleApp1;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string json = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]";
JArray o = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
List<object?> list = new();
foreach (JToken jToken in o)
{
    list.Add(jToken.ToObject(typeof(int)));
}

Car car = new Car();
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = car.GetType().GetFields();
foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
{
    fieldInfo.SetValue(car, list);
}

Thanks a lot!

you can’t call SetValue with a different type, than the property you are setting into is expecting. You will need to turn the variable list to the type List first.

but why do that ordeal anyway, and not serialize the instance car itself, and deserialize it? why only a single property of car?

Here an approach to turn a list object into a list of unknown type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939552/convert-listobject-to-listtype-type-is-known-at-runtime

You can convert your List from object? to int via Linq:
List<object?> objList = new();

// ...your code for reading the data...

List<int> intList = objList
    .Where(item => item != null) // Filter out null objects
    .Select(item => (int)item) // Cast each object to int
    .ToList(); // Convert the result to list


Or as Rand Random suggests in the comments, you can just us OfType:
List<int> intList = objList.OfType<int>().ToList();

Note that OfType not only automatically filters out null values but also values that cannot be cast.
This means that if your list contains { 1, "2", null }, the code with Where and Select will result in an exception in (int)item cast, while the code with OfType<int>() will result in a list only containing 1.

You can also use Cast, it works similar to .Select(item => (int)item):
List<int> intList = objList
    .Where(item => item != null)
    .Cast<int>()
    .ToList();


or just .OfType<int>().ToList()

Since you know that you want to deserialize as List<int>, you should declare the variable as List<int> instead of List<object> type.
List<int> list = new();

Note that it can be simplified to:
List<int> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(json);

If you are keen on working with JArray:
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
List<int> list = jArray.ToObject<List<int>>();

Looking for generic way:
public List<T> DeserializeToArray<T>(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
}

Caller:
List<int> list = DeserializeToArray<int>(json);

Also, you can initialize to the Car instance easily without the need of reflection:
Car car = new Car();
car.PriceList = list;

Make the PriceList as property.
public class Car
{
    public List<int> PriceList { get; set; }
}


As OP said The GenericTypeArgument of List can be int, String, Object..etc. - which I assume means at compile time it is unknown what type the list will be and it should be figured out at runtime
